# Popup window command works on powershell but not when i run it as windows bash script file

Tags: windows, powershell

I run a command on powershell and it works fine. when i make it into a windows bash script file the same exact command i get " is not recognized as an internal or external command"

I run these commands on powershell and they work fine:

```
$shell = (New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell)
$shell.Popup("Test",0,"Data Backup Info")
```

But when i make a windows bash file with the exact same commands, I keep getting
" '$shell' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."

It is the exact same command, why won't it run when I set it up as a Batch File?

Comment: See https://www.onlogic.com/company/io-hub/how-to-enable-bash-for-windows-10-and-11/

Comment: Powershell isn't Bash.  A simple Google search will explain the difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i make a windows bash file

The error message you received ("not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file") implies that you are trying to create a *batch file* (`.cmd` or `.bat`), i.e. a file interpreted by *Windows*' legacy shell, `cmd.exe`, rather than by [`bash`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), a shell for *Unix*-like environments.

From a *batch file*, executing *PowerShell* commands requires calling via PowerShell's *CLI* ([`powershell.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe) for *Windows PowerShell*, [`pwsh`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh) for [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md)).

E.g., with `powershell.exe`, from a `.cmd` or `.bat` file:

```
@echo off & setlocal

powershell -c "(New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell).Popup('Test', 0, 'Data Backup Info')"
```

Comment: thank you very much for your response. that is what I needed. and I apologize for the noob questions but the differences between Bash, Batch,Powershell,CMD,Terminal, etc. have really thrown me off.  It was a beginners mistake, but thank you for your patience!